# Java processbuilder run a program(.exe) in background

Tags: java, multithreading

I have tried this code. But the .exe program jumps and come out. I just want to use it's effect not the window.

```
    ps = new ProcessBuilder("\\.exe","\\A").start();
```

how to set that invisible like other java frames

```
    frames.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this using pure java. There is a difference between running process and accessing the window created by other process. To achieve this goal you have to use plarform specific APIs, for example JNI/JNA either directly or indirectly.

Take a look on this project: https://github.com/twall/jna
I hope it can be helpful.

Comment: cant I access the Task Manager and then close that?

Comment: If you want to run specific application it is much easier. Use `java.awt.Robot` to run task manager. Then simulate `Alt-f4` with robot to close the window.

Comment: I ain't that kinda expert :p can u give me an example? plz :)
I dnt know how to use java.awt.Robot to run an application. simulation of <code>Alt-f4</code> is far away :p:p

Comment: Correct is done but I cant upvote cuz I dnt have enough reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute exec() method of Runtime that returns Process instance or use ProcessBuilder class methods.

```
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("file.exe");
```