# How to run mongod process in background using Java Process Builder?

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot, processbuilder

I'm trying to run a mongod process on a Linux host using Java ProcessBuilder API in a Spring Boot Application running on the same host.
I tried the following ways.

#### Method 1 : Directly running mongod in bash

```
String confpath;
String []commands = {"./mongod","-f",confPath,"&"};
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands)
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

Running a process with the above array makes ProcessBuilder take & as a mongod parameter and gives an error that & is not an option.

#### Method 2 : Using bash -c "command"

```
String exec = String.format("./mongod -f %s",confPath)
String []commands = {"/bin/bash","-c",String.format("\"%s\"",exec),"&"}
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands)
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

This method exits with code 127 which means that this command wasn't found.
I tried using absolute paths as well, Any insights would be helpful.

I'm running a JAR file if that helps.

Comment: Do you have mongodb installed on the Linux host? Also if you write on command line mongod it works? An embedded mongo instance is not sufficient?

Comment: @pringi I'm using mongo binaries. Also yes it works on the command line.

Comment: String.format("\"%s\"",exec) -> any reason why you are formatting? cannot use exec string directly? {"/bin/bash","-c",exec,"&"}. Also check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957493/java-processbuilder-run-a-program-exe-in-background